# Kazam save file at current time

Tags: 20.04, video-recording, kazam

[image: kazam filename]

***AutoSave enabled***
I want to save all my screencast file names in current recorded period (for instance, 2020-08-19_20_00_00.webm).

Current is *kazam_screencast000X.webm*

Answer (score 2):

there is a feature request for that...

https://github.com/hzbd/kazam/issues/41

Comment: yeah, that's been added by me.